# Getting COUNT() of a related tag

Tags: php, mysql

I've hit a wall with my mySQL knowledge.

To explain it more clearly here are my tables (a pretty standard setup for tags):

```
keywords
---
keyword_id (ai)
keyword
```

-

```
topics_keywords
---
t_k_id (ai)
topics_id
keyword_id
```

-

```
topics
---
topics_id
etc
```

Now, lets say that `keywords` table has the following entries:

```
keyword_id || keyword
1 || baseball
2 || sports
```

And topics_keywords has the following entries:

```
t_k_id || topics_id || keyword_id
1 || 1 || 1 
2 || 1 || 2
3 || 2 || 1
```

So maybe you can see what im trying to do.

If someone inputs 'baseball' I want to get a COUNT for how many topics that share a related keyword.  In the above example, `baseball` and `sports` are both shared keywords for `topics_id: 1`.

So if someone inputs `baseball` how would I get the count() that displays there is 1 other topic out there, named `sports` that shares a topic with `baseball`?

Comment: Do you want to get the `COUNT` or the other keyword named `sports`?  They sound exclusive.

Comment: its not possible to get both the count() and the keyword?  I always thought count could just be appended onto the results

Comment: The total count would just be the number of rows then

Comment: On an unrelated note, I think your t_k_id column is unnecessary. It's probably better to drop that column and use (topics_id, keyword_id) as the primary key.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand you correctly you might want to look into running something like this:

SQL Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/9e6be/6

```
SELECT COUNT(*)                                                             
  FROM keywords
  JOIN topics_keywords
 USING (keyword_id)
 WHERE keyword != 'value'
   AND topics_id IN (
         SELECT topics_id
           FROM keywords 
           JOIN topics_keywords 
          USING (keyword_id)
          WHERE keyword = 'value' );
```

That is, you're selecting the count of topics_keywords that do not have the keyword you're looking for but do have the topics_id of the keyword you're looking for.

Comment: this is pretty neat, and if I remove the != 'keyword' it returns the appropriate count. Im sure I can work with this code to get it exactly how i need it. Thanks!